# run a minishift with debug logging level

Tags: openshift-origin, minishift

How to run a minishift with debug logging level?
I tried

```
minishift logs --v 8 -f
```

but it doesn't work.
According to the https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2216951 (requires a RedHat developer account to view the full version) 8 log level should be what I need.

```
0 - Errors and warnings only
2 - Normal information
4 - Debugging-level information
6 - API-level debugging information (request / response)
8 - Body-level API debugging information
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying the ``--server-loglevel`` option when running ``minishift start``? See ``minishift start --help`` for details of options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be run as

```
minishift start --show-libmachine-logs -v 5
```

where

- --show-libmachine-logs will show libmachine logs
- -v n - shows n level deep logs

More here https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/command-ref/minishift_start.html.